# Unsatisfied dependencies for type X with qualifiers @Default at injection point [BackedAnnotatedField] @Inject @Default

Tags: java, dependency-injection, ejb, cdi

I'm facing a problem with the injection.

I have cut down the files to provide a basic overview of what I'm doing.

UsersApi.java (REST service)

```
package com.example.api;
@Path("/users")
@RequestScoped
public class UsersApi  {
  @Inject
  private UsersService delegate;
  @GET
  @Path("/{lanId}")
  @Consumes({ "application/json" })
  @Produces({ "application/json" })
  public Response userDetails(userID,httpServletRequest){
    Response userDetails= delegate.userDetails(userID,httpServletRequest);

    return Response.ok(userDetails,MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_TYPE).build();
    }
}
```

UsersService.java

```
   package com.example.api;
    public interface  UsersService {
    public  Response userDetails(String lanId, HttpServletRequest httpServletRequest);
    }
```

UsersServiceImpl.java

```
package com.example.api.impl;
@Stateless 
public class UsersApiServiceImpl implements UsersApiService {
    @Override
    @TransactionAttribute(TransactionAttributeType.REQUIRED)
    public Response userDetails(String lanId, HttpServletRequest httpServletRequest) {
    System.out.println(lanId);
    }
}
```

When I deploy the ear file in weblogic it throws

```
Unsatisfied dependencies for type UsersService with qualifiers @Default at injection point [BackedAnnotatedField] @Inject @Default private com.example.api.UsersApi.delegate at com.example.api.UsersApi.delegate(UsersApi.java:0)
```

Comment: Do you have the `beans.xml` file with `bean-discovery-mode="none" or "annotated"` or  in your classpath?

Comment: Yes, I have the bean.xml and bean-discovery-mode="all"

Comment: Strange. You probably meant `beans.xml` and not `bean.xml`. One thing I see is you're using `HttpServletRequest` in the EJB. Actually, Servlet technology is not supposed to be used in the business tier! It is better you create some JavaBean component and pass the information you need from the request instead of passing the request itself.  It would be helpful if you could post the screenshot of your directory structure.

Comment: @beginner Forgive me if I am missing something, but you are injecting `UsersService` which, from you code, is an interface (that is OK) but you don't have any implementation. At least in the snippet shown here. Therefore, there is no real bean to inject.

Comment: What container are you deploying this to?